# JMeter Regular extraction looking to correlate a value between two dynamic variables

Tags: regex, jmeter

im in a bit of a pickle

im trying to extract a value where the value before it and after it are very redundant.
[sample of the response with the desired value highlighted][1]

now since the value before it and after it are dynamic that narrows down the regex values i can rely on.

and validating every idea i have gives back a wider string.

how can i extract this value?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYUXf.png

Answer (score 0):

[JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) therefore using Regular Expressions for extracting data from it is not the best idea.

Consider using i.e. [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) which allows using arbitrary [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries allowing fetching data from JSON in flexible, readable and more powerful way.

If you [post the code in text form and not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) I could come up with a proper JsonPath expression.